# Get the error on flutter-v 2.2.0 Error: 'intl.NumberFormat' can't be used as a type because 'intl' doesn't refer to an import prefix

Tags: flutter, dart

: Error: 'intl.NumberFormat' can't be used as a type because 'intl' doesn't refer to an import prefix.
final intl.NumberFormat totalNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: The getter 'intl' isn't defined for the class 'AppLocalizationsEn'.

- 'AppLocalizationsEn' is from 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_en.dart' ('.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_en.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'intl'.
  final intl.NumberFormat totalNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
  ^^^^
  : Error: 'intl.NumberFormat' can't be used as a type because 'intl' doesn't refer to an import prefix.
  final intl.NumberFormat countNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: The getter 'intl' isn't defined for the class 'AppLocalizationsEn'.
- 'AppLocalizationsEn' is from 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_en.dart' ('.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_en.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'intl'.
  final intl.NumberFormat countNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
  ^^^^
  : Error: 'intl.NumberFormat' can't be used as a type because 'intl' doesn't refer to an import prefix.
  final intl.NumberFormat countNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: The getter 'intl' isn't defined for the class 'AppLocalizationsEn'.
- 'AppLocalizationsEn' is from 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_en.dart' ('.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_en.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'intl'.
  final intl.NumberFormat countNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
  ^^^^
  : Error: 'intl.NumberFormat' can't be used as a type because 'intl' doesn't refer to an import prefix.
  final intl.NumberFormat totalNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: The getter 'intl' isn't defined for the class 'AppLocalizationsEs'.
- 'AppLocalizationsEs' is from 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_es.dart' ('.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_es.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'intl'.
  final intl.NumberFormat totalNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
  ^^^^
  : Error: 'intl.NumberFormat' can't be used as a type because 'intl' doesn't refer to an import prefix.
  final intl.NumberFormat countNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: The getter 'intl' isn't defined for the class 'AppLocalizationsEs'.
- 'AppLocalizationsEs' is from 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_es.dart' ('.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_es.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'intl'.
  final intl.NumberFormat countNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
  ^^^^
  : Error: 'intl.NumberFormat' can't be used as a type because 'intl' doesn't refer to an import prefix.
  final intl.NumberFormat countNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  : Error: The getter 'intl' isn't defined for the class 'AppLocalizationsEs'.
- 'AppLocalizationsEs' is from 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_es.dart' ('.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations_es.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'intl'.
  final intl.NumberFormat countNumberFormat = intl.NumberFormat.compactLong(
  ^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.